# "cannot open source file bits/stdc++.h" in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

If I put the above line at the top of my `program.cpp` file, it gives me the following error message:

> cannot open source file "bits/stdc++.h"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a Standard C++ header file, and Visual C++ does not implement it. You should not use it even if the compiler you are using does implement it, as it makes your code immediately non-portable, possibly even between different versions of the same compiler.

Comment: The question is how to fix not why not to fix. Sure this is not good practice but this is a very commonly used in competitive programming and good for quick prototyping.

Answer (score 11):

It's an internal GCC header file. There is no guarantee that it will work anywhere else; even using it with GCC itself is poor practice for many reasons. **Do not use it, ever.**

> How can I fix this?

Include those standard headers which you actually need. For example, if you need `std::cout`, then include `<iostream>`. If you need `std::string`, then include `<string>`. If you need `std::ifstream`, then include `<fstream>`.

As those are standard headers, they are guaranteed to work everywhere.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a good free online source to find out which headers are needed for which component of the standard library. Let's take a non-obvious one, like `std::ifstream`. You just search for that name and you'll find http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream. There, it says:

> Defined in header `<fstream>`